# Selecting a span Element which is hidden using selenium

Tags: css, selenium

I have the following type of element,

```
<td class="x-btn-mc">
<em id="ext-gen141" class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on">
   <button id="ext-gen33" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">
        <div class="mruIcon"/>
        <span>Legacy CaseMon</span>
   </button>
</em>
</td>
```

- In this I am unable to select exact co-ordinates of drop down arrow,
- And the xpath for all the list of options are also same( `<//*[@id='ext-gen141']>` )
- Only thing varies is Span (Say I have to select "Cases",then span value becomes `<Span>Cases</Span>`)

Can anyone please help me choosing the different value
Thanks..

Comment: Please share your selenium code also..

Comment: Here is my code....WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathConstant));
Select select = new Select(dropdown);
select.selectByVisibleText(textToSelect);

Comment: Did you try this xpath ? - //div[@class='mruIcon']/span

Comment: @Lalitha : Instead of only command implementations can you show original code with locator's you used?

Comment: I don't think **Select** class will help in this case, as the dropdown is not created using the [**HTML select tag**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). So, if you can share the HTML code of two more options and the **"div element"** that signifies the dropdown that will be helpful in sorting this one out. Thanks. :)

Comment: Here is the HTML code <div id="ext-gen32" class="support-servicedesk-navigator">
<table id="ext-comp-1007" class="x-btn support-servicedesk-sb Custom43Mru mruIcon x-btn-noicon" cellspacing="0" style="width: 250px; height: 26px;">
<tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="x-btn-ml">
<td class="x-btn-mc">
<em id="ext-gen146" class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on">
<button id="ext-gen33" class="x-btn-text" type="button">
<div class="mruIcon"></div>
<span>My Notifications</span>
</button>
</em>
</td>

Comment: X-Path I used is :-  //*[@id='ext-gen146'],